# How do I get sidebar part of the application content with Semantic UI?

Tags: css, semantic-ui

Here I a new to Semantic-UI!

I am trying to get a page layout like below where the header is fixed at top taking 100% width, and sidebar which has the menu, and the content side-by-side. I want this work on mobile also where the Sidebar menu is collapsed with toggle switch.

```
---------------------------
Header                    |
---------------------------
Sidebar|     Content      |
  with |                  |
 Menu  |                  |
---------------------------
```

If I attach sidebar to the toggle button, it appears that the sidebar gets the position: fixed and left:0. So it outputs like this:

```
---------------------------
       |Header            |
Sidebar|-------------------
  with |     Content      |
 Menu  |                  |
       |                  |
---------------------------
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c4bngzL7/1/

Sure this is a very common layout, what am I missing?